# that + past participle usage

Tags: passive-voice, relative-clauses, past-participles, reduced-relative-clauses

I know how to use relative clause in reduced form i.e. I saw the dog barking.(I saw the dog which barked)

But in a technical book, I see the following sentence and can't figure out.

> This function performs some action appropriate to the condition **that
>   generated the signal**

I think that the author forgot to put **is** before **the signal**. If not, is there any usage form like **that + past participle**? Or, what is the usage of **that** here? Can you rewrite the sentence with same meaning? Is **generated** past simple here?

Comment: I think if you reword it like **The function performs the appropriate action based on the condition that generated the signal**. 
it makes a little more sense. The sentence itself is correct though.

Comment: still non-sense, because my problematic part is "that generated the signal" part

Comment: If you add the word ***is***, it would have to be: **that is generated by the signal**. But what's wrong with: the condition that generated the signal?? There is no clause reduction possible here.

Comment: what is the usage of **that** here? Can you rewrite the sentence with same meaning? Is **generated** past simple here?

Comment: The word ***that*** in your context functions as a [pronoun / determiner](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/which), just as it would be if you substituted it with ***which***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, **generated** is not being used as a participle but as the simple past of **generate** in the active voice. It would totally subvert the intended meaning to insert **is**, an insertion that would change the verb into a present passive construction. **That** is the subject of the relative clause and refers to **condition**.

The meaning is **At some time after a condition generates a signal, the function will perform the action appropriate to that condition.**

Answer (score 2):

*generated* is not a participle: it's an ordinary past form. *that* is a relativizer, equivalent to *which*.

1. Some condition generated the signal.
2. This function performs some action appropriate to the condition.

   Appropriate to *which** condition? . . . appropriate to the condition that/which generated the signal.

Comment: Thank you so much. But the view of the sentence is present simple. I confused and can't figure out why past simple used there. Intriguing

Comment: @snr: It would be just as valid if you rephrased your example to *This function performs some action appropriate to the condition **which / that  generates** the signal.* Present or past tense ***generate*** is effectively a stylistic choice (but of course a speaker / writer might be influenced by the fact that the signal must have already been generated before it can be detected and acted upon).